# Canon G7000 series printer driver for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Has anyone created a printer driver for the Canon G7000 series printers that will work on Ubuntu 18.04? The settings/devices shows the printer, but there is no driver available and it will not print anything. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Start testing generic drivers but first read this post and use Canon linux drivers. You probably won't have all feature but you should be able to do some basic printing. I've been doing this for years on different printers. 
https://wiki.debian.org/Canon

I would start by trying this G6000 series linux drivers:
https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_g_series/pixma-g6040.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)

Last idea try installing generic PPD from Canon or possibly PCL drivers.
http://www.openprinting.org/driver/Postscript-Canon/

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess I am answering my own question. I did a sudo apt update and then a sudo apt upgrade after I got the printer up on the network and successfully printed from my mac. I then opened devices/printers and noticed that the original name for the printer is CANON_G7000_series and that it does not accept jobs. But when I opened the options dialog, I found that there was now a selection for the G7000 series under the Canon selection for drivers. I installed that driver, then added a printer and that allowed me to select the G7000 printer, which does accept jobs and now I can print. Seems convoluted to me, but it works, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Linux driver for my Canon Maxify GX-7050 which works fine here:

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/megatank-inkjet-printers/all-megatank-inkjet-printers/maxify-gx7020?tab=drivers_downloads